# Autofac and Signalr

Tags: signalr, autofac

I've posted this on the Autofac group with no luck.

I'm using Autofac3,0.1, SignalR 1.0.0pre2 and the Autofac.SignalR.3.0.0 packages from Nuget. I'm registering types with Autofac but 
on resolution I'm getting a

"No parameterless constructor defined for this object."

error

My hub looks like

```
public class UserHub : AuthenticatingHub
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public UserHub(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }
```

and my container builder like this:

```
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

        var serviceAssemblies = Assembly.Load("Services");
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(serviceAssemblies).AsImplementedInterfaces();
        builder.RegisterType<UserHub>();

        var container = builder.Build();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new Autofac.Integration.SignalR.AutofacDependencyResolver(container);
```

Where 'Services' references the IUserService

This is code that worked with previous versions of SignalR and Autofac but with a different Autofac dependency resolver. Any pointers would be welcome,

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure to set your resolver before calling MapHubs() on the route collection, a reference to the resolver, at that time, is passed into the infrastructure right there. Setting a new resolver after calling MapHubs won't do anything.

Comment: Thanks Yves. I'd just found exactly the same thing. I was mapping the hubs in PreApplicationStartMethod and that's firing before the resolver is set

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot missing from the documentation on the internet. I did a write up on using SignalR 2.0 and Autofac together because Autofac's documentation is not complete:

I did a blog write about this, but I do that website down, here is HTML of that blog article:

Heavily using DI via Autofac in an MVC application and having troubles with Signalr 2.0?

Have you followed Autofacs documentation and installed the Autofac.SignalR Nuget package:
https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/SignalRIntegration

There is multiple problems with Autofac’s documentation and the Autofac.Singalr Nuget package is for SignalR 1.0.

So first, let’s fix using SignalR 2.0. You simply have to give the Autofac.SignalR package a nudge in the right direction, add the following to your Web.config:

```
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">

        <dependentAssembly>

            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="" />

            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.1.1.0" />

        </dependentAssembly>

    </assemblyBinding>

</runtime>
```

And now the actual code that will actually work:

```
public interface IConversationHub

{

    System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnected();



    void SendNotifications(long _account_id, int _partition_id, List<long> _userIds,

        DTO.ConversationEventMessage _message);

}



[Authorize]

public class ConversationHub : Hub, IConversationHub

{

    readonly ILifetimeScope _hubLifetimeScope;

    private uTextAPP.AppLayer.IManageUsers _ManageUsers { get; set; }

    private uTextAPP.AppLayer.IManageUserConnections _ManageUserConnections { get; set; }

    private uTextDDD.ServiceLayer.IReportUserConnections _ReportUserConnections { get; set; }



    public ConversationHub(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)

    {

        // Create a lifetime scope for the hub.

        _hubLifetimeScope = lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope();



        // Resolve dependencies from the hub lifetime scope.

        _ManageUsers = _hubLifetimeScope.Resolve<uTextAPP.AppLayer.IManageUsers>();

        _ManageUserConnections = _hubLifetimeScope.Resolve<uTextAPP.AppLayer.IManageUserConnections>();

        _ReportUserConnections = _hubLifetimeScope.Resolve<uTextDDD.ServiceLayer.IReportUserConnections>();

    }



    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnected()

    {

        //var username = Context.User.Identity.Name; //this is the user_id!! yay!

        var user = _ManageUsers.GetCurrentUser();

        var _issues = new Issues();



        if (user == null || user.account_id == 0)

            return base.OnConnected();



        var conn = new user_connection

               {

                   connection_id = Context.ConnectionId,

                   user_id = user.user_id

               };



        _ManageUserConnections.CreateUserConnection(user.account_id, user.user_id, user.partition_id, conn, _issues);



        return base.OnConnected();

    }





    internal static void SendNotifications(long _account_id, int _partition_id, List<long> _userIds, DTO.ConversationEventMessage _message, IEnumerable<uTextDTO.AppLayer.user_connection> _connections )

    {

        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ConversationHub>();





        if (_connections == null) return;



        foreach (var c in _connections)

        {

            if (_userIds.Any(_userIds.Contains))

            {

                if (context.Clients.Client(c.connection_id) != null)

                {

                    context.Clients.Client(c.connection_id).receiveNotification(_message);

                }

            }

        }

    }





    public void SendNotifications(long _account_id, int _partition_id, List<long> _userIds, DTO.ConversationEventMessage _message)

    {

          var _issues = new Issues();

        SendMessage(_account_id, _partition_id, _userIds, _message, _ReportUserConnections.GetAllUserConnectionsByDaysBack(_account_id, -1L, _partition_id, 1, _issues))

        ;



    }



    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)

    {

        var user = _ManageUsers.GetCurrentUser();

        var _issues = new Issues();



        if (user == null || user.account_id == 0)

            return base.OnConnected();



        var original = _ManageUserConnections.GetUserConnectionByConnectionId(user.account_id, user.partition_id,

            user.partition_id, Context.ConnectionId, _issues);



        if (original != null && original.user_connection_id != 0L)

        {

            var mod = new user_connection().CopyModelExt(original);

            mod.is_active = false;



            _ManageUserConnections.UpdateUserConnection(user.account_id, user.user_id, user.partition_id, original.user_connection_id,mod, original, _issues);

        }



        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);

    }



    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)

    {

        // Dipose the hub lifetime scope when the hub is disposed.

        if (disposing && _hubLifetimeScope != null)

            _hubLifetimeScope.Dispose();



        base.Dispose(disposing);

    }

}
```

First off, note with the above code, public override Task OnDisconnected cannot be trusted, it does not fire and is not a reliable way to manage disconnects from SignalR, this method may catch some disconnects. Luckily for my requirements, I can just ignore connections that are more than a day old.

Next note, with the above code, internal static void SendNotifications. SendNotifications has to be static so that the SignalR Context does not throw runtime errors when accessing.

And finally note the static method is passed connections from the caller, the public exposed method of SendNotifications. I needed an instance of IReportUserConnections in SendNotifications but IReportUserConnections is not static and cannot be static to be injected by Autofac properly. And so I cannot use IReportsUserConnections in static void SendNotifications, so I instead solved this problem with the public version of SendNotifications.

For the Autofac Container:

```
public static class SimpleInjectorInitializer

{

    public static IContainer Container;



    public static void Initialize()

    {

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();



                   // Register the SignalR hubs.

                    builder.RegisterHubs(typeof(uTextAPP.SignalR.ConversationHub).Assembly);



        uTextMVC.RegisterMe.Register(builder);



        Container = builder.Build();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver(Container));



        var signalRDependencyResolver = new Autofac.Integration.SignalR.AutofacDependencyResolver(Container);

        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = signalRDependencyResolver;

    }

}
```

And one of the big parts that is missing on the internet, how to actually use your IoC injected ConversationHub to send notifications:

```
public Lazy _ConversationHub { get; set; }
_ConversationHub.Value.SendNotifications(account.account_id, account.partition_id, userIds, convoEv);
```

You have to make sure you register your Hub with Autofac in your Register.me so that _ConversationHub is initialized:

```
  container.RegisterType<SignalR.ConversationHub>().As<SignalR.IConversationHub>().InstancePerLifetimeScope().PropertiesAutowired();
```

Comment: The link seems to be dead.

Comment: @Gebb I apologize, I took down this website, looking to see if I have the post in my backup, it was a wordpress post

Comment: @Gebb Ok I found the blog article and updated my answer, hope it helps